# Do we count the increment statement when we determine an algorithm's complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I read a book where the author count the increment statement in a for loop (the update) as one step but I saw a lecture slide where the professor didn't count the increment statement at all. Do we take into account the increment statement when we analyze the complexity of an algorithm or do we not ?

Comment: Can you show an example of this increment statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do we take into account the increment statement when we analyze the complexity of an algorithm or do we not ?

*It doesn't matter.* The exact number of statements inside a loop doesn't affect the asymptotic runtime of an algorithm, as it can only increase the runtime by a constant factor (if even that). You can safely handwave the exact number of steps involved in a loop, so long as you count it as at least one.

Comment: Here [link](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/focs/ch03.pdf) on page 93, the author counted the increment in the Example 3.1. Will the analysis still be correct if he didn't count the increment ?

Comment: The exact running time formula will be slightly different based on how "steps" are counted. Page 93 hasn't quite gotten to the point of explaining asymptotic runtime yet, but once you get there, you'll find that the result is always `O(m)`.

Comment: But what if I encounter a question that asks to give exact running time formula for a pseudo code or an implementation of an algorithm ? Do I count the increment or not ?

Comment: If this comes up in homework or in a test question, and it isn't clear from the question, ask your professor or TA. It's not a distinction that ever matters in practice; the way you count steps in this context is entirely arbitrary.